# Converting Decimal to Binary using pointers

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to access the memory of my program in order to convert a decimal input to a binary output. What I'm currently attempting to do is access the starting address of my integer with @input, then increment the address by 1 every time and writing the value of this address to the console.

For example:

- Input: 2
- Output: 00000000000000000000000000000010

Could anyone give me some tips (or pointers? ha ha) on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code? It'll explain better than words...

Comment: PByte(NativeInt(@Input) + 0)^, PByte(NativeInt(@Input) + 1)^, ..

Comment: Converting decimal to binary this way won't work because incrementing the address won't give you the next bit in the number but the next byte.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to convert an integer into a binary string representation? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are asking.

You can convert a value to its binary representation using a function like this, taken from the Indy unit `IdGlobalProtocols`.

```
function IntToBin(Value: LongWord): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 32);
  for i := 1 to 32 do begin
    if ((Value shl (i-1)) shr 31) = 0 then begin
      Result[i] := '0'
    end else begin
      Result[i] := '1';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

On the other hand, perhaps you are simply asking how to increment an address by one. Well, get the address and add one to it. There are two ways you might do this. If you want to deal with the address as a number, convert it to a pointer sized integer:

```
var
  Address: UIntPtr;
....
Address := UIntPtr(@someVar);
```

And now you can perform arithmetic. For instance:

```
inc(Address);
Address := Address + 8;
```

and so on.

If you actually wish to perform pointer arithmetic and then de-reference the pointer, it's easier to use a pointer type. So, if you wish to pick out bytes, then you can do so like this:

```
var
  BytePtr: PByte;
....
BytePtr := PByte(@someVar);
```

Now you can read a byte with

```
b := BytePtr^;
```

And the next one is:

```
inc(BytePtr);
b := BytePtr^;
```

Finally, if you wish to pull out the bytes that make up an integer, there is the `LongRec` type for that. Write `LongRec(someIntVar).Bytes[i]` to read one of the 4 bytes that make up an integer. Similar records `WordRec` and `Int64Rec` exist. These types are defined in `SysUtils`.

Comment: I think he's talking about incrementing the address because he thinks he's got bit-addressable memory, and he's trying to retrieve successive binary digits

Comment: @NickBarnes Oh gosh, I'd not even thought about that!

Comment: Khm... .might be off and stupid question, but... I don't really understand the reason that the first function in the answer above ( IntToBin ) does not work correctly if set from 32 to 16 (and 31 to 15)..?  ://
I needed the result of length 8, so I copied the string with Index 25 with count 8, and it works for me, but am just trying to understand the workflow of the function...

thanks.

Comment: @JustMarc I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to convert number into a binary string of a length 8 or 16 instead of 32. But it didn't work... So I'm not sure whether it's even possible - whether it must be of a length 32 for some reason, or...?

Comment: @justmarc The exact same approach can be used for byte or word. It works fine. You must have made a mistake.

Comment: so using `function IntToBin(Value: LongWord): string;` with code

  `SetLength(Result, 8);
  for i := 1 to 8 do begin
    if ((Value shl (i-1)) shr 7) = 0 then begin`   (everthing else is the same; only numbers changed) should work??

Comment: @justmarc Why are you passing a 32 bit value? Pass an 8 bit value? Your code pulls off the most significant byte. Also why are you not asking a question?

Comment: Tried Integer instead of LongWord as well, but same result..
Hm, well, thought it's some trick I just don't understand and have no knowledge about, not some serious stuff...
Will post a question now though. I'm really interested in what's going on.
Thanks.

Comment: @justmarc Integer is also 4 bytes. Use byte.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did that too. Same result.
Posted as new question. Thanks. :)